# Facing 'HTTP request not authorized' error accessing WCF service with authentication using anonymous auth

Tags: c#, authentication, anonymous

I have a wcf service that does database operations. I want to access the methods in this service with authentication. For this, I turned on anonymous authentication in IIS and entered the username-password that I created. But when I want to call my GetSicil method in visual studio, I get this error. What would be the reason?

i have looked for similar errors but the problem is not fixed

Comment: I called the method as follows: 

client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "xXx";
            client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Xxx";

            user = client.GetMethod(Convert.ToInt32(txt_ID.Text));

Comment: security in my web.config:

<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />

</security>